# Change PDF page size without re-scaling a content (CLI)

Tags: linux, command-line, pdf

### Question

I have a PDF with a non-standard page size.
I would like to change PDF canvas size to A4 without re-scaling the content.

I can receive the expected result with Printing to PDF (picture below, original content is a black rectangle). However, I would like to achieve the same result using Linux CLI.
[image: What I would like to receive]

How can I change PDF page size **without** rescaling the content, using the Linux command line?

### Investigation

I have tried to use pdfjam: `pdfjam --outfile out.pdf --paper a4paper in.pdf`. Unfortunately, it scales to fit `in.pdf` and thats unacceptable for me.

Also I tried cpdf: `cpdf -scale-page a4portrait in.pdf -o out.pdf` scales content to the page size.

Moreover, found [PdfScale](https://github.com/tavinus/pdfScale). However it can only scale content or change page size with fitting the content.

The similar problem has been described [here](https://superuser.com/a/697469), but the author used GUI application (not CLI)

Comment: It's a little hard to tell what exactly you mean with "scaling". PDF documents are vector images so they should scale indefinitely. What you could try regardless, is crop to content, and then put that onto an A4 page with one of the tools you mentioned. I suggest checking out `pdfcrop` it should be available in one of the LaTeX packages.

Comment: Could be one you looking for: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/696716/295060